# How to get one product name whose switch or toggle is on from whole parent div in cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

This is one testcase which i want to execute but I am not getting idea how to put if condition in it.
**Parent div html code.**

```
<div class="row collection-listing pro-list-collection"><div class="col-md-3 add-a-product"><a class="bg-white text-center"><div class="table-cell"><img src="/images/add-product.svg" alt="" loading="lazy"><span>Add a product</span></div></a></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Women T-shirt with V-Neck</div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/3/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" checked=""><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Beanie with Embroidery</div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/19/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Men Tanktop</div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/31/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Coffee Mug </div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/38/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Men Basic T-shirt</div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/50/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 added-product"><div class="bg-white text-center"><button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button><div class="pro-title">Women Basic T-shirt</div><div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block"><div class="product-design"><div class="product-design-output"><img src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/345/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div></div></div><div class="product-switch"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label><em>Use as Main Product</em></div></div></div></div>
```

**One product's div html code**

```js
<div class="col-md-3 added-product">
  <div class="bg-white text-center">
    <button class="btn-default">Click to edit</button>
    <div class="pro-title">Women T-shirt with V-Neck</div>
    <div class="image-bg-set d-inline-block">
      <div class="product-design">
        <div class="product-design-output">
          <img
            src="https://pci-designer-steps-server.shirtee.cloud/product-images/3/651?backgroundColor=%2300000&amp;size=s"
            style="
              width: 150px;
              height: 150px;
              background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            " />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-switch">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" />
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
      <em>Use as Main Product</em>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How the front end looks like**
[image]

Comment: Is this the html for toggle ON or OFF `<input type="checkbox" checked="">`.

Comment: This is for toggle off
<input type="checkbox">
This is for toggle on
<input type="checkbox" checked>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, to me you need to identify the cards and what they contain.

Each card has the class `added-product`, so to verify the description of the selected product

```js
cy.get('input[checked]')                  // which is checked?
  .closest('.added-product')              // the card containing this switch
  .contains('Women T-shirt with V-Neck')  // has this description
```

To check there are 5 other product which are not selected, and have other descriptions

```js
cy.get('input:not([checked])')
  .closest('.added-product')
  .should('have.length', 5)
  .and('not.contain', 'Women T-shirt with V-Neck')
```

---

BTW `.parents('.added-product')` also works, it scans all ancestors until the class is found.

---

To get the title when one product has been checked

```js
cy.get('input[checked]')                  // which is checked?
  .closest('.added-product')              // the card containing this 
  .find('.pro-title')                     // the title element
  .its('text')                            // it's text
  .then(productText => {                  
    console.log(productText)
  })
```

You usually don't do `if(...) {} else {}` in a test, because you're not writing an app, you are testing for expected conditions on the page after some state has been set (like toggling the product switch).

The test should either meet the condition or fail, it's not too useful to log the state like you have done in the comment.

Comment: I don't know what it contains. every time it contains different. I want to get that title whose toggle is on. I have tried below code, it gives an error that you can't use child command first.


        if(cy.get('.pro-list-collection').closest('.added-product') .find('input[checked]')){

           cy.parents('.pro-title').then(function(text2){
               cy.log(text2.text())
               
           })
        }
        else{
            cy.log('No test product')

        }
}

Comment: Ok, yeah it's in the title - "How to get one product name", sorry I was too focused on the HTML. You don't do `if(...)` in Cypress, I'll add another section to the answer.